# Bitnami WAMP stack Phpmyadmin default username password not working on Windows 8.1

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, bitnami

I have installed Bitnami Wamp stack on windows 8.1. Phpmyadmin with these combinations

1) user name : administrator, Password : bitnami

2) Username : root, Password : bitnami

3) Username : root, Password : EMPTY

None work. I tried the host name as localhost and 127.0.0.1

I dont remember setting any password myself during installation.

Please help as I am not able to log into phpmyadmin

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I tried in the bitnami forum and I have not got any reply yet. Somebody please help me.

Thanks and Regards
Prabhakar Shanmugam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami WAMP requests a password during the installation. The default user is "root" and the password is the same that you set during the installation.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your help. It worked.

Comment: Beltran I have one more question though, I installed bitnami wordpress app. But it seems you can only install only one app per exe. I mean it goes to the app folder, and If I want one more copy of bitnami wordpress for another project on the same bitnami wamp stack, it doesnt allow you to do that. Any solution ?